# Autoload + Namespace works in localhost, but don't work in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have this a code that works in localhost but doesn't work in my server, I have a folder called platform the path is `/var/www/html/platform`

platform/**.htaccess**

```
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /var/www/html/platform/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

plataform/**autoload.php**

```
function __autoload($className) {
$file = $className . '.php';
if(file_exists($file)) {
     require_once $file;
}else{
    //fail
}
```

plataform/**index.php**

```
include ('autoload.php');

$controller = new application\controllers\Controller();
```

plataform/application/controllers/**Controller.php**

```
namespace application\controllers;

class Controller{

}
```

In my localhost this code works, but in my server i receive the following message:

> Fatal error: Class 'application\controllers\controller' not found in
>   /var/www/html/platform/index.php on line 12

How can I solve this problem? I'm using Ubuntu `PHPMyAdmin on 14.04 (Digital Ocean)`.

Comment: Does your autoloading conform to the PSR-4 standard? Besides you look into spl_autoloading.

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi PSR-4 standard? spl_autoloading? This is new for me... I don't understand what you talking about... You have an tutorial or something similar?

Comment: i'm going to post an answer on how i handle my autoload, works anywhere i implement

Comment: what about this: `$file = './'. $className . '.php';`

Comment: @Kazz don't work...

Comment: @Lacrifilm ok then add to `__autoload` this: `$className = str_replace((DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/' ? '\\' : '/'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the autoloader.
 *
 * Based off the official PSR-4 autoloader example found here:
 * https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md

Here is a simple autoloading class, should deal with namespacing too

```
class Autoload {

    public function __construct(){

    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

        // project-specific namespace prefix
        $prefix = 'App\\';

        // For backwards compatibility
        $customBaseDir = '';

        // base directory for the namespace prefix
        $baseDir = $customBaseDir ?: __DIR__ . '/';

        // does the class use the namespace prefix?
        $len = strlen($prefix);
        if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
            // no, move to the next registered autoloader
            return;
        }

        // get the relative class name
        $relativeClass = substr($class, $len);

        // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
        // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
        // with .php
        $file = rtrim($baseDir, '/') . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $relativeClass) . '.php';

        // if the file exists, require it
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
        }   
    });
}
}
```

save in Autoload.php class. include path and initialize to use.. $autoload = new Autoload;